# When there are no domain models, is the ViewModel for the Model used to keep the DAL out of the ViewModel of the View?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am currently working on an application that has all its entities coming from straight from Linq2SQL. Trying to find a way to keep everything cleanly separated, I added a domain model for the type that came from Linq2SQL and wrapped that with a ViewModel.

This added a little bit of complexity to my code, as I have a service layer and in it when initializing I got the entity from L2S, newed my domain class, and filled it with whatever data was in the entity.

When I wanted to insert the item back into the database in L2S, I ran into a problem which made me do the reverse: fill an entity with the data from the domain class. At this point I started to doubt if I was on the right path, so I started to think about what I have done wrong, or just possibly thought was the right way but ultimately wasn't.

I ended up thinking that wrapping the entity instead of filling a domain model and wrapping *that*, was maybe the right way to go in this situation. If I wouldn't do something like this, I would need to have a using statement in the ViewModel of my View pointing to the DAL. Maybe I'm mistaken, but as far as I read (in books, internet articles), that is not a clean separation of concerns.

So, hence my question:

When there are no domain models, is the ViewModel for the Model used to keep the DAL out of the ViewModel of the View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. However I see a lot of confusion in the comunity about the MVVM pattern. A lot of people "Wrap" the model in the ViewModel, like what you're doing, and this is wrong.

The Model is basically your L2S Objects.

The ViewModel, exposes the L2S objects directly, and handles interaction logic, i.e. handle commands, object updates, etc. (doesn't wrap anything, just as a link to them).

Wraping is wrong, let's say for example that you want something that is too complex for a converter, yet you need to have it on your Entity (BusinessObject or whatever comes out of L2S - Your ORM framework), you should extend your Entity to support this.

I'll give you some examples, however these are from a slightly different architecture:

- Entity Framework 4.1
- Prism, MVVM implementation
- MEF Dependency Injection Container

This is a list of Tasks in this application, the final result is a view like project with a gantt chart.

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using Sigep.Common.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Sigep.Common.DataSelfTracking;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sigep.WPF.Controls.Cronograma
{
    [Export(typeof(TarefasListViewModel))]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class TarefasListViewModel : NotificationObject
    {
        private IDataManager _data;
        private IRegionManager _regionManager;

        private static ObservableCollection<Tarefa> _tarefas;
        private static List<Sigep.Common.DataSelfTracking.Tarefa> _tarefasList;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public TarefasListViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IDataManager data)
        {
            _data = data;
            _regionManager = regionManager;

            _tarefas = new ObservableCollection<Tarefa>(_data.TarefaList.OrderBy(T => T.Codigo));
            _tarefasList = _data.TarefaList;

            _data.Loaded += new EventHandler<DataManagerEventArgs>(Data_Loaded);

            _NovaTarefa_Command = new DelegateCommand(this.NovaTarefa);
        }

        void Data_Loaded(object sender, DataManagerEventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                _tarefas.Clear();
                foreach (var tarefa in _data.TarefaList.OrderBy(T => T.Codigo)) _tarefas.Add(tarefa);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Promotores);
            }
            , CancellationToken.None
            , TaskCreationOptions.None
            , Indra.Injection.ServiceLocator.MefContainer.GetExportedValue<TaskScheduler>());
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Tarefa> Tarefas
        {
            get
            {
                return _tarefas;
            }
        }

        public static void refreshTarefas()
        {
            _tarefas.Clear();
            foreach (var tarefa in _tarefasList.OrderBy(T => T.Codigo)) _tarefas.Add(tarefa);
        }


        public IEnumerable<PromotorIndex> Promotores
        {
            get
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (var promotor in _data.Candidatura.Promotores.OrderBy(p => p.Nome))
                {
                    yield return new PromotorIndex()
                    {
                        Nome = promotor.Nome,
                        Index = index++
                    };
                }
            }
        }
        private ICommand _NovaTarefa_Command;
        public ICommand NovaTarefa_Command { get { return this._NovaTarefa_Command; } }
        private void NovaTarefa()
        {
            Tarefa tarefa = new Tarefa { Inicio = DateTime.Now, Fim = DateTime.Now, Nome = "",Actividade = _data.ActividadeList.FirstOrDefault() };

            IRegionManager _region = Indra.Injection.ServiceLocator.MefContainer.GetExportedValue<IRegionManager>();

            foreach (var v in _region.Regions["CrudCronogramaTarefas"].Views) _region.Regions["CrudCronogramaTarefas"].Remove(v);

            _region.Regions["CrudCronogramaTarefas"].RequestNavigate("/TarefaDefault", nr => { });
            var view = ((FrameworkElement)_region.Regions["CrudCronogramaTarefas"].ActiveViews.FirstOrDefault());

            ((UserControlCrudBase)view).Permissions = Sigep.WPF.Controls.UserControlCrudBase.PermissionsType.Update;

            view.DataContext = tarefa;
        }
    }

    public class PromotorIndex
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
    }

    // Converters
    public class DataInicioPercentagemConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var tarefa = (Tarefa)value;
            var candidatura = Indra.Injection.ServiceLocator.MefContainer.GetExportedValue<IDataManager>().Candidatura;

            double totalDias = candidatura.DataFim.Subtract(candidatura.DataInicio).Days;
            double diasTarefaInicio = tarefa.Inicio.Subtract(candidatura.DataInicio).Days;

            return new GridLength((diasTarefaInicio / totalDias * 100), GridUnitType.Star);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public class DataMeioPercentagemConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var tarefa = (Tarefa)value;
            var candidatura = Indra.Injection.ServiceLocator.MefContainer.GetExportedValue<IDataManager>().Candidatura;

            double totalDias = candidatura.DataFim.Subtract(candidatura.DataInicio).Days;
            double diasTarefa = tarefa.Fim.Subtract(tarefa.Inicio).Days;

            return new GridLength((diasTarefa / totalDias * 100), GridUnitType.Star);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public class DataFimPercentagemConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var tarefa = (Tarefa)value;
            var candidatura = Indra.Injection.ServiceLocator.MefContainer.GetExportedValue<IDataManager>().Candidatura;

            double totalDias = candidatura.DataFim.Subtract(candidatura.DataInicio).Days;
            double diasTarefaFim = candidatura.DataFim.Subtract(tarefa.Fim).Days;

            return new GridLength((diasTarefaFim / totalDias * 100), GridUnitType.Star);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    [ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(Brush))]
    public class IndexColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(Brush))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a Brush");

            switch((int)value)
            {
                case 0:
                    return Brushes.Red;
                case 1:
                    return Brushes.Green;
                case 2:
                    return Brushes.Blue;
                case 3:
                    return Brushes.Purple;
                case 4:
                    return Brushes.Yellow;
                case 5:
                    return Brushes.Brown;
                default:
                    return Brushes.Pink;
            }
       }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(int))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a int");

            var color = (Brush)value;

            if (color == Brushes.Red) return 0;
            else if (color == Brushes.Green) return 1;
            else if (color == Brushes.Blue) return 2;
            else if (color == Brushes.Purple) return 3;
            else if (color == Brushes.Yellow) return 4;
            else if (color == Brushes.Brown) return 5;
            else return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it has specific converters there, some objects we use to create some extra UX functionality and handles command interaction directly from the View.

The Task (here called Tarefa from portuguese naming) itself is an Entity Framework Self Tracking Entity, and it is extended by adding a second partial class definition. The STE T4 template itself isn't that much tweaked, most of the customization is done by adding extra partial class definition to objects we want to customize.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Sigep.Common.DataSelfTracking.Utils;

namespace Sigep.Common.DataSelfTracking
{
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay("{Codigo}")]
    public partial class Tarefa
    {
        private const double GRID_HEIGHT = 32;

        public Actividade ActividadeNum 
        {
            get 
            {
                return Actividade;
            }
            set
            {
                Actividade = value;
                this.Numero = this.Actividade.Tarefas.Max(X=> X.Numero)+1;
            }
        }


        public Candidatura CandidaturaActual
        {
            get
            {
                if (RelsRecursosInternosTarefas.Count > 0)
                    return this.RelsRecursosInternosTarefas[0].RecursoInterno.Estabelecimento.Promotor.Candidatura;
                else if (RelsRecursosExternosTarefas.Count > 0)
                    return this.RelsRecursosExternosTarefas[0].RecursoExterno.EntidadeExterna.Promotores[0].Candidatura;
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public double TotalHoras
        {
            get
            {
                return RelsRecursosInternosTarefas.Sum(r => r.Duracao) + RelsRecursosExternosTarefas.Sum(r => r.Duracao);
            }
        }

        public string Codigo
        {
            get
            {
                return Actividade.PKID.ToString() + "." + Numero;
            }
        }

        public int DuracaoDias
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)Math.Ceiling(DateTimeUtils.CalculateBusinessDays(Inicio, Fim));
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<AlocacaoPromotorTarefa> PercentagensParticipacao
        {
            get
            {
                var altura = GRID_HEIGHT / CandidaturaActual.Promotores.Count;

                int index = 0;
                foreach (var promotor in CandidaturaActual.Promotores.OrderBy(p => p.Nome))
                {
                    var totalRI = RelsRecursosInternosTarefas.Where(r => r.RecursoInterno.Estabelecimento.Promotor == promotor).Sum(r => r.Duracao);
                    var totalRE = RelsRecursosExternosTarefas.Where(r => r.RecursoExterno.Estabelecimento.Promotor == promotor).Sum(r => r.Duracao);

                    yield return new AlocacaoPromotorTarefa() {
                        Actual = totalRI + totalRE,
                        Restante = TotalHoras - totalRI - totalRE,
                        Index = index++,
                        GridHeight = altura
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        public DateTime GetPrimeiroDiaAno(int ano)
        {
            if (ano < Inicio.Year || ano > Fim.Year) throw new Exception("Ano Invalido");
            else if (Inicio.Year == ano) return Inicio;
            else return new DateTime(ano, 1, 1);
        }

        public DateTime GetUltimoDiaAno(int ano)
        {
            if (ano < Inicio.Year || ano > Fim.Year) throw new Exception("Ano Invalido");
            else if (Fim.Year == ano) return Fim;
            else return new DateTime(ano, 12, 31);
        }

        public int GetDuracaoDias(int ano)
        {
            if (ano < Inicio.Year || ano > Fim.Year) return 0;
            else if (ano == Inicio.Year && ano == Fim.Year) return (int)DateTimeUtils.CalculateBusinessDays(Inicio, Fim) + 1;
            else if (ano == Inicio.Year) return (int)DateTimeUtils.CalculateBusinessDays(Inicio, new DateTime(ano, 12, 31)) + 1;
            else if (ano == Fim.Year) return (int)DateTimeUtils.CalculateBusinessDays(new DateTime(ano, 1, 1), Fim) + 1;
            else return (int)DateTimeUtils.CalculateBusinessDays(new DateTime(ano, 1, 1), new DateTime(ano, 12, 31));
        }

        public double GetDuracaoMeses(int ano)
        {
            if (ano < Inicio.Year || ano > Fim.Year) return 0;
            else if (ano == Inicio.Year && ano == Fim.Year) return DateTimeUtils.CalculateMonths(Inicio, Fim);
            else if (ano == Inicio.Year) return DateTimeUtils.CalculateMonths(Inicio, new DateTime(ano, 12, 31));
            else if (ano == Fim.Year) return DateTimeUtils.CalculateMonths(new DateTime(ano, 1, 1), Fim);
            else return 12;
        }
    }

    public class AlocacaoPromotorTarefa
    {
        public double Actual { get; set; }
        public double Restante { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public double GridHeight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's mostly getters that return stuff that we want to bind to the View directly, that isn't apart of the Model. This practice makes development very fast, as writing converters can be quite complex for some types of exposures.

This is a lot of code, but hopefully will give you an idea of what to write on the ViewModel and what to write on the Model, how to extend the Model and how you bind stuff around.

Comment: The wrapping of the model I got from Josh Smith. The reasoning behind this is to be able to add extra functionality that otherwise doesn't belong in the domain class, or better yet, when you don't have any domain classes like I have. For example, implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface is in my case (without domain model) not easy to do. I guess you could do it by extending the entity class, perhaps, but I do no know the works with it. But then there is as well the question of keeping everything in its own layer. I guess the View and its ViewModel are what is the presentation layer

Comment: Then you have a service layer, Domain Classes, and a DAL. My question pertains more with M-MV-V-VM -> Model - ModelView, View - ViewModel than with MVVM. That is, to not have an entity class or links to the DAL in the presentation layer, i.e. a separation of concerns. I was thinking of my situation and how it could be accomplished and thought that the ModelView (the wrapper for the entity) could be of use in the separating.

Comment: Well, by having the Service Layer you detach yourself from the DAL. You either are transporting generated entities by the proxy or the real entities, either way they are your Model on the Client. You can also extend the entities generated by the proxy class, to implement the INotifyProperty changed, however this is not a good aproach. What you really want is to reuse the entities at the DAL level into your client, that is simply done by having the DAL project on the solution of the client and making sure that the reuse classes option is ticked when you generate the web service reference.